# my php code is not working on Internet explorer 9?

Tags: php, internet-explorer-9

I am writing code in php using session ,its working on Mozilla as well as on chrome but on internet explore its not working ? please help me to resolve this problem `

`` <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$_SESSION['IGNITE']="IGNITE -";
$_SESSION['IGNITE_price']=39.95;
$_SESSION['IGNITE_qty']+=1;
$_SESSION['total_ignite']+=39.95;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{

$_SESSION['REBUILD']="REBUILD -";
$_SESSION['REBUILD_qty']+=1;
$_SESSION['REBUILD_price']=39.95;
$_SESSION['total_rebuild']+=39.95;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
$txt_rebuild=$_POST['txt_rebuild'];
$txt_ignite=$_POST['txt_ignite'];
$_SESSION['IGNITE_price'];
$_SESSION['REBUILD_qty']=$txt_rebuild;
$_SESSION['IGNITE_qty']=$txt_ignite;
$_SESSION['total_rebuild']=$_SESSION['REBUILD_price'] * $_SESSION['REBUILD_qty'];
$_SESSION['total_ignite']=$_SESSION['IGNITE_price'] * $_SESSION['IGNITE_qty'];
}
$grand_total=$_SESSION['total_rebuild']+$_SESSION['total_ignite'];
?>` ``

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with the Browser, because the codes runs on the server

Comment: PHP runs on the server, so it's not related to browser at all. There is something wrong in your code.

Comment: There must be some proplem with code . Please post your code

Comment: It doesn't work in IE for sure, since browsers can't run PHP.

Comment: But but.... It runs on chrome!!!!

Comment: Check whether cookie is enabled in IE, Cookie should be enabled to work session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has nothing to do with your browser, it runs in server.

Check whether cookie is enabled in IE, Cookie should be enabled to work session.

Comment: I dont see anything that STOPS you executing ONLY IN IE, debug line by line good luck :)